# Compiling Pinecone app is not compiling correctly into a Exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pinecone

I built a python app inside `visual studio code` that uses the `Pinecode API` and `Library`. The app runs just fine inside `Visual Studio Code` and runs on the local host.

I used `Pyinstaller` to compile the app. It compiled just fine, however, when I go to run the `exe` file, I am getting the following error.

```
> C:\Users\mtschetter\OneDrive - \Projects\python_app_local\dist>app.exe
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "app.py", line 2, in <module> 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked 
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module 
File "agent.py", line 2, in <module> 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked 
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module 
File "pinecone\__init__.py", line 4, in <module> 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked 
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module 
File "pinecone\core\utils\constants.py", line 33, in <module> 
File "pinecone\core\utils\__init__.py", line 53, in get_environment 
File "pathlib.py", line 1058, in read_text 
File "pathlib.py", line 1044, in open FileNotFoundError: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\MTSCHE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI51162\\pinecone\\__environment__' 
[7032] Failed to execute script 'app' due to unhandled exception!
```

I seems as though it is having a hard time compiling the `Pinecone` library and the dependencies with it. How can I solve this? Thank you.

I tried to re-install and re-start my computer, but that did nothing.

I tried to look through Pinecone's docs, but could not find anything specific to this problem.

Comment: We need a [MRE] included in the question -- the shortest possible code and set of steps to reproduce the problem without any changes whatsoever.

Comment: `Python` wasn't invented to create `exe` files and `PyInstaller` doesn't create real `exe` file but self-extracting `zip` file. And often `PyInstaller` has problem to add all needed files in `exe` - and you may have to manually add needed modules using special file `spec`. You may see this problem in many questions about `PyInstaller`

Comment: [Using Spec Files — PyInstaller 6.2.0 documentation](https://www.pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html)